# Python: Weird error when clearing array for specified string

Tags: python

I want to clear array from specified string - for example "test", so I wrote this function. But I get this error "IndexError: list index out of range". What is wrong with this code?

```
def clearOutPut(array):
    size = len(array) - 1
    for x in range(0, size):
        if array[x].find('test') > 0:
            array.pop(x)
            clearOutPut(array)
    return array
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is you are changing the array as you are scanning through it. You are making it shorter as you scan through, so when you get to a point where x is larger than the length of your modified array it throws an error.

Instead consider:

```
def clearOutPut(array):
    new_array = [element for element in array if element.find('test') == -1]
    return new_array
```

That is just a fancy way of doing the following:

```
def clearOutPut(array)
    # First let's create an empty array
    new_array = []

    # Loop through elements of array (not indexes!)
    for element in array:
        # Check it doesn't contain 'test', if so, append the element to new_array
        if element.find('test') == -1:
            new_array.append(element)
    # Return the new_array we have built
    return new_array
```

Comment: But when I pop array then I call same function again with this modified array. So its like loop until 'test' is not found. Isnt it supposed to work this way?

Comment: @HighFive I understand your thinking, but eventually the program will return to the earlier loops, and eventually the value of x in that loop will get big enough to cause a problem.

Comment: I should explain that the solution I have posted is called a list comprehension. It's a very powerful tool in Python. I'll write out a for loop version below.

Comment: Ok, now I see it. Thanks for help.